# akeeba 3.7.6 downgrade to akeeba 3.6.12

Tags: backup, joomla2.5, downgrade

I recently updated to Akeeba 3.7.6 (that yellow danger sign made me to! :) - silly me, didn't read anything about that before) and unfortunately none of our hosting servers is using php 5.3 yet (they use php 5.2.17) so I cannot put my website live (it's running on internal dev server now). And I don't think they are looking into upgrading any time soon I'm afraid.

Is there any option how to fix it?

Of course I tried to uninstall akeeba and install older version which didn't show as a good idea AT ALL! - it stopped working completely (had backup, thanks god!).

Any help very appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

Alright, probably no option how to downgrade Akeeba (have tried many ways!) but if anyone gets to the same desperate situation there is a solution! :)

I used newest Akeeba 3.7.6 to wrap up our site, put the *.jpa file to our server, unwrap it using newest kickstart.php, everything was working fine to the point when I needed to run an installation then I got this error...

Akeeba Next Generation Installer For Joomla! requires PHP 5.3 or later

So I went to phpMyAdmin on devbox where I exported current database my devsite was using, went to phpMyAdmin on my hosting server, imported it, change configuration.php file and vuala :)

Don't know if that's the best solution ever but we are live now and everything (except Akeeba) is working correctly...hopefully our host will upgrade soon!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily downgrade Akeeba to 3.6.12 just don't forget to uninstall FOF (and possibly everything else by author:Nicholas K. Dionysopoulos).

Update:
In addition of removing newer version of Akeeba components you also have to remove FOF (Framework on Framework) by Nicholas K. Dionysopoulos / AkeebaBackup.com in Joomlas Extension Manager.
If FOF is not removed in extension manager, installing older version of Akeeba will give you 'Access denied' when trying to run Akeeba.

So, in your Joomla backend go to Extension->Extension Manager->Manage
select all Akeeba plugins, admin tools (by Nicholas K. Dionysopoulos, if you have them installed) AND FOF plugin/library (by Nicholas K. Dionysopoulos) and click 'Uninstall'.

After that installing older versions of Akeeba backup should be no problem.

Comment: Loco, Majki is trying to downgrade, but isn't sure how to. If you could offer steps to do so, that would be useful. You should try to get clarification as to why installing an older version "...didn't show as a good idea AT ALL!"

Answer (score 1):

You can change the restoration script that Akeeba Backup will include in your backup in the Akeeba Backup configuration page. Just change "Embedded restoration script" (in Advanced Configuration) to `Akeeba Backup Installer` and you'll be able to restore your site. The new ANGIE installer requires PHP 5.3.

But remember that even if you can restore the site, you won't be able to use any recent version of Akeeba Backup on your host with PHP 5.2.